# Exibindo dados com React JS

Tags: javascript, html, react

Bom dia pessoal, estou tentando exibir na tela uma mensagem digitada pelo usuário, algo bem simples porem como sou novo no React não tenho muito noçao de como fazer isso. Bom, o código abaixo foi até aonde eu consegui chegar, ele nao esta pegando os dados do input e nem retornando quando eu clico no botao. Se puderem me ajudar eu ficarei muito grato, Obrigado !

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Button2 extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)

       this.state = {
           text: 'Your Name Here',
       }

   }

   clicked = (event) => {
       this.setState = ({ text: event.target.value })
   }

   handlerSubmit = e => {
       e.preventDefault()
       this.setState = { text: this.state.text }
   }
   render() {
       return (
           <form onSubmit={this.handlerSubmit}>
               {this.state.text}
               <input type="text" />
               <button onClick={this.clicked}>Click on me</button>
           </form>

         )

      }
  }

  export default Button2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está naquele momento de aprendizado o nome do componente não faz referencia ao componente e o que ele representa, mas, você está precisando alterar o estado do `input` `text`, então precisa programar isso que é no evento`onChange` desse `input`, exemplo:

```
handlerOnChangeInput = e => {   
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
}
```

sendo esse função genérica podendo alterar para todo o estado do `input`, mas, para que isso funcione o nome do `input` tem que ser passado igual o nome da variável de estado criado que no seu caso em especifico é `text`.

De um modo geral é feito assim:

```
handlerOnChangeInput = e => {   
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
}
```

mas, fica restrito somente nesse `input` (*pode ser feito assim também não há problemas, só vai escrever um pouco mais porque o código só vai funcionar para esse `input` e se houver mais que precisa guardar estado então tem que escrever para cada um, por isso eu coloquei o genérico antes, escolha o melhor para você*)

O exemplo completo e funcional:

```js
class Button2 extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props)

       this.state = {
           text: 'Your Name Here',
       }

   }

   handlerSubmit = e => {
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log(this.state.text);
   }
   
   handlerOnChangeInput = e => {   
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    this.setState({[name]: value});
   }
   render() {
       return (
           <form onSubmit={this.handlerSubmit}>
               {this.state.text}
               <input type="text" value={this.state.text} name="text" id="text" onChange={this.handlerOnChangeInput} />
               <button onClick={this.clicked}>Click on me</button>
           </form>

         )

      }
  }
ReactDOM.render(<Button2/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Aguarde ...</div>
```

<sup>***Observação:*** o `button` nesse caso resgata o valor do estado do componente na chave criada, ou seja, é diferente, que no caso para pegar o valor do `text` precisa digitar `this.state.text`.</sup>

Comment: Olá, vc poderia me explicar melhor essas duas linhas de código ? 
const {name, value} = e.target;
this.setState({[name]: value});

e eu tbm fiquei na duvida o pq vc colocou um value, um name e um id no input mas nao colocou nada no botão. Se puder me responder eu ficarei grato ! Obrigado.

Comment: `const {name, value} = e.target;` é um como se você fizesse `const name = e.target.name;` e `const value = e.target.value;`  eu quero desconstruir `e.target` [leia](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao) e a parte ***value, um name e um id no input mas não colocou nada no botão*** é porque tem que ser feito assim eu coloquei `name` e `id` mas, só precisava do `name` para que a função genérica funcionasse e o botão é um submit do form então o valor é resgatado do estado quando submit o form. @GiovanniManganotti

Comment: Ok, Obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: Se for a resposta do seu pergunta @GiovanniManganotti aceite